# Find out parent key when a certain child value is met with jq

Tags: json, jq

Here's the json:

```
{
    "vendors": {
        "vendor1": {
            "vendor_version": "LS TT1706-POL",
            "vendor_name": "toyota"
        },
        "vendor2": {
            "vendor_version": "LSGS-2002-RC",
            "vendor_name": "honda"
        },
        "vendor3": {
            "vendor_version": "LS1903",
            "vendor_name": "suzuki"
        }
    }
}
```

I basically need the jq expression to get "vendor2" when I am given LSGS-2002-RC. I've tried using select, map, variables, and every combination thereof. 
here is something that didnt work:

`jq -r '.vendors|to_entries[]|.value|select(.vendor_version=="LSGS-2002-RC")'`

Basically I always end up with the keys vendor1, vendor2, etc... stripped

I am a little stumped. Note that the json structure or values cannot be altered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, but the right filter should have been to use the `select()` function on the `.value.vendor_version` and pick out the key name

```
jq -r '.vendors | to_entries[] | select(.value.vendor_version=="LSGS-2002-RC").key'
```

Also don't pass in dynamic strings to the function, use placeholders like variables

```
jq -r --arg vendor "LSGS-2002-RC" '.vendors | to_entries[] | select(.value.vendor_version == $vendor).key'
```

An alternate, *less* readable version than `select()` would be to use `keys[]`

```
.vendors | keys[] as $k | if .[$k].vendor_version == "LSGS-2002-RC" then $k else empty end
```

Comment: Great answer @inian. I had simplified the issue for posting but did use env variable. I always spend so much time with jq it's insane.